# Failed to Install Torque in Ubuntu16.04: configure: error: TORQUE needs libxml2-devel in order to build

Tags: 16.04, server

I tried to install Torque in Ubuntu16.04LTS with this command:

```
./configure --with-libxml2=/usr/bin/xml2-config
```

but this error is always thrown:

```
configure: error: TORQUE needs libxml2-devel in order to build
```

This happens for all versions of Torque I tried, including the newest version. The error is always the same.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try to install the devel package of *libxml2*. `apt-get install libxml2-dev`

Comment: Thanks very much, Thomas:) I have done it, but it did not work out.....

Comment: What do you mean by *did not work out*. A bit more specific error description would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it clearly, Thomas. Indeed, after installing libxml2-dev,  the same error of needing libxml2-devel still appeared.

Comment: I met exactly the same problem. Don't know how to do